# IOHelper::fileExists always false

Tags: plugin-development

I use the following code:

```
$sourcePath = $assetRecord->source->sourceType->getBasePath();
$folderPath = $assetRecord->getFolder()->path;
$path = $sourcePath.$folderPath.$assetRecord->filename;

if (IOHelper::fileExists($path)) {
    $content = IOHelper::getFileContents($assetRecord->url);
    craft()->request->sendFile($test, $content, array('forceDownload' => true));
}
```

The fileExists always return false. I use the image all over the site without any problems. Also the `$path` variable return normal path from inside the public folder.

This code lives inside a custom plugin.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

`IOHelper::fileExists()` will return false for a few reasons:

1. Either PHP's [realpath](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) or [is_file](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) returns false. i.e. the given path doesn't exist or PHP doesn't have executable permissions on the folders leading up to that path or read permissions on the file itself.
2. You're using a case-sensitive file system and you're passing in a different cased path/filename than what's on the file system.